# In Python, how can I remove items from a list based on a list of strings?

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list of strings that I want to remove items from. I have a list of keywords that I am searching for in these items.  I cannot seem to get the output I am looking for.  I am not sure if regular expressions are the right way to handle this.
I want the output to be ['/item/page/cat-dog', '/item/page/animal-planet']

```py
valid = ['/item/page/cat-dog', '/item/page/animal-planet', '/item/page/variable']
keywords = ['cat','planet']


for item in valid: 
    #a = re.findall()
    #
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want this code to do

Comment: `[s for s in valid if any(q in s for q in keywords)]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a flat list out of list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0):

Python comes with the handy keywords `in` and `not in` to test if an object is or is not in a list.

for your problem, you can simply do :

```
new_list = []
for item in valid: 
    if os.path.basename(item) not in keywords:
        new_list.append(item)
```

`os.path.basename` gives the name of the files without the arborescence.
new_list will then contain all the elements of `valid` in which the filenames were not in `keyword`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, and based on [@dan-d's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870074/in-python-how-can-i-remove-items-from-a-list-based-on-a-list-of-strings/55870364#comment98400442_55870074) what you need is

```
[s for s in valid if not any(q in s for q in keywords)]
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments and other answers, the [in](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html?highlight=membership#membership-test-operations) operator may be used to check if a string is a substring of another string.  For the example data in the question, using `in` is the simplest and fastest way to get the desired result.

If the requirement is to match '/item/page/cat-dog' but not '/item/page/catapult' - that is only match the *word* 'cat', not just the sequence *c-a-t*, then a regular expression may be used to do the matching.

The pattern to match a single word is `'\bfoo\b'` where `'\b'` marks a word boundary.

The alternation operator `'|'` is used to match one pattern or another, for example `'foo|bar'` matches 'foo' *or* 'bar'.

Construct a pattern that matches the words in `keywords`; call [re.escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) on each keyword in case they contain characters that the regex engine might interpret as metacharacters.

```
>>> pattern = r'|'.join(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(keyword)) for keyword in keywords)
>>> pattern
'\\bcat\\b|\\bplanet\\b'
```

Compile the pattern into a [regular expression object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects).

```
>>> rx = re.compile(pattern)
```

Find the matches: using [filter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#filter) is elegant:

```
>>> matches = list(filter(rx.search, valid))
>>> matches
['/item/page/cat-dog', '/item/page/animal-planet']
```

But it's common to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> matches = [word for word in valid if rx.search(word)]
>>> matches
['/item/page/cat-dog', '/item/page/animal-planet']
```